# Как создать виджет (обратная связь, форма какая-либо..)?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где почитать, может где исходники есть этого *** добра..
Все, что ни гуглится, так это живосайты и прочее подобное.
А мне бы хотелось просто выезжающую или в виде модального окна форму обратной связи, с уведомлением на почту. Прикреплена к краю окна (скрины прикрепил).
Спасибо!

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Если нужна просто выезжающая или появляющаяся форма, то проще будет сделать самописную)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дополнение к вышеизложенному комментарию - как пример:

```js
// объявляем переменные
const feedback = $('#feedback');
const start = feedback.find('.start');
const background = feedback.find('.background');
const modal = feedback.find('.modal');

// инициализируем фидбэк
initFeedback();

// ф-ия закрытия (immediate - плавно закрыть или моментально)
function hideFeedback(immediate = false) {
  if (immediate) {
    modal.hide();
    background.hide();
  } else {
    // тут можно какую-нидь анимацию скрытия поставить, но я использую стандартный fadeOut
    modal.fadeOut(() => {
      background.fadeOut();
    });
  }
}

// ф-ия показа
function showFeedback() {
  // тут можно какую-нидь анимацию показа поставить, но я использую стандартный fadeIn
  background.fadeIn(() => {
    modal.fadeIn();
  });
}

// ф-ия инициализации
function initFeedback() {
  // тут делаем, чтобы кнопка была по центру по вертикали (50% - половина ширины + зависимость из CSS), а также фиксим погрешность, которая образовалась при CSS transform: rotate(-90deg);, а именно - высота кнопки - ее ширина + зависимость из CSS
  const right = start.css('right');
  const top = start.css('top');
  start.css({
    right: `calc(${start.outerHeight(true) - start.outerWidth(true)}px + ${right})`,
    top: `calc(${start.outerWidth(true) / 2}px + ${top})`
  });

  // по умолчанию скрываем фидбэк моментально
  hideFeedback(true);
}
```

```css
#feedback {
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#feedback>* {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#feedback>.start {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

#feedback>div.start {
  background: url("https://1ep4fb1p9c8v44y1114fn0qi-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Contact-Us-Button.png") center / contain no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  width: 150px;
}

#feedback>div.start:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-10px);
}

#feedback>.background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#feedback>.modal {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>Контент</p>
<div id="feedback">
  <div class="start" onclick="showFeedback()"></div>
  <!-- Или вариант со стандартной кнопкой: -->
  <!-- <button class="start" onclick="showFeedback()">Обратная связь</button> -->
  <div class="background" onclick="hideFeedback()"></div>
  <div class="modal">
    <h3>Обратная связь</h3>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="email" required placeholder="Email" />
      <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас в примере синтаксис css-свойства `background` некорректный, кнопка в итоге прозрачная

Comment: Это быстро правиться)

Comment: Kvilios, спасибо большое!

Comment: @andreymal, так да, только при чём здесь `background`? прозрачность задается кнопке через `opacity: .5;` да и консоль если открыть видно, что `background` применился корректно: http://joxi.ru/Dr89zGNtoKWQxm

Comment: Да, почему то файл бэкграунда не подгружается ни в какую в мозилле, хром его открывает.

Comment: @Kvilios потому что синтаксис background некорректен, картинки нет и на кнопке просто нечему отображаться. opacity здесь абсолютно ни при чём, у вас background кривой

Comment: Увидел, спасибо. Поставил +
Мозила не понимает "`/ contain`" в свойстве `background`. Вынес его отдельно в `background-size` и все заработало.

Comment: @Kvilios это не «Мозилла не понимает», это вы нарушили спецификацию CSS, по которой background-size должен стоять только после background-position, и «Мозилла» строго следует этой спецификации. То, что картинка отображалась в хроме — баг хрома ;)

Comment: @andreymal, да, от порядка в мозилле тоже зависит, странно, но тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background#Значения так и написано - цитирую: "Свойству можно указывать одно или более значений из данного списка в любом порядке:". Хром в этом плане оказался умнее. Также цитирую из описания: "Значения могут идти в любом порядке, браузер сам определит, какое из них соответствует нужному свойству."

Comment: @Kvilios а про size по вашей ссылке написано «This property must be specified after <position>», такие дела)